# Any way to rewrite an URL and give PHP variable to it?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I want to rewrite my URL's, each url looks like below :

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/projet-in.php?idProjet=57
```

And each project got a special name given by database.

My question here is : Is this possible to rewrite my url's like that ? :

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/ProjectName
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Answer (score 1):

if the project name is unique, yes it is possible : search your project by name instead of searching by id

use this rewrite rule :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # not a dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # not a file**
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ projet-in.php?name=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
```

this way, when the user goes to `http://foo.fr/projectName` apache will theat the request as `http://foo.fr/projet-in.php?name=projectName` so you will get the project in GET parameters in PHP

your new php code will be

```
<?php
$db = new Database();

$project = $db->findByProjectName($_GET['name']);
```

Comment: this way, the url http://foo.fr/projectName will become  http://foo.fr/projet-in.php?name=projectName

Well I want the first URL, I wont use the 2nd one

Comment: when the user go to `foo.fr/projectName`, apache will rewrite the url to  `foo.fr/projet-in.php?name=projectName` in php you will get the project name in the GET parameters